# nodejs foreach not returning correct value

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, amazon-s3, foreach

I'm trying to use this function to get some total counts from my log files in s3, and then add them to a total varaible to return.  But i can't get the callback correct.

I've tried the callback in the end of the foreach loop, and also in the "
else" at the end, but in either case totalRowCount is always zero bcz the statements start executing right away.  Not sure what i'm doing wrong, thanks for any help.

```
function getRowCount2(token, params, callback){
  var totalRowCount = 0,
    TextDecoder = textEncoding.TextDecoder,
    i = 0;
  if(token) params.ContinuationToken = token;

  s3.listObjectsV2(params, function(err, data){

      i = data.Contents.length;
      data.Contents.forEach(function(file, index) {            

          s3.getObject({Bucket: params.Bucket, Key: file.Key}, function(err, data) {

              zlib.gunzip(data.Body, function (err, result) {
                    var extractedData = JSON.parse(new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(result));
                    totalRowCount = totalRowCount + parseInt(extractedData.rowcount, 10);

              });

              if ((index+1) == i){
                console.log('callback ' + totalRowCount);
                return callback('', totalRowCount);
              }
          });

       });

    if(data.IsTruncated)
      getRowCount2(data.NextContinuationToken, params, callback);
    else          
      //return callback('', totalRowCount);
  });
}

getRowCount2('', params, function(error, data) {
     // check if equal
     if (mycount == data) { //success }
  });
```

I've stripped out logging and error handling to help reading.

Comment: Shouldn't `if ((index+1) == i){` block be in the callback of `zlib.gunzip()`?

Comment: I don't think so.  zlib.gunzip() is going to run for each object/file i return.  that block will increase the totalrowcount variable each time it unzips a file, and after all objects/files are run, then i need to return the totalrowcount

Comment: I see what you're saying, it could be in there.  I tried it, and right now it only spits back to me one logs worth of count.  I have two logs with 60 and 21.  It usually just returns one or the other.  Does the same thing the way i have it above (outside of zlib.gunzip block)

Comment: when i log the index of the foreach function, i can see that it works on the 2nd array element first sometimes...actually in the zlib.gunzip block.  so i ran this, and i get 60, which is my second logs value.  hmmm, and that is the difference, right at start of foreach index is in ascending order.   But within getObject( zlib.gunzip(.....)) it first looked at 2nd index.  so when i check "does index + 1 equal 2", it does on the first iteration, and returns

Comment: Yes, you should not look at the index but rather count how many items you have processed already. Because you cannot guarantee that 1st item will be completely processed before 2nd item... and so on. See my answer to get a clear way of doing it. I used a closure to do the count.

Comment: ok, thanks @RaphaMex will give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is:

> How to call callback function **once** at the end of the forEach loop and **after all my asynchronous functions have finished** their work on each item?

The trick with callbacks is to not get mixed up and do the right thing at the right place. Because we are not in a synchronous context, we need extra work that I have put here in a wrapper.

Your example is a bit complicated to run. So I have built a simplified example that you can reuse. It simply counts lines of several files and displays the sum at the end.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const files = ["a.txt","b.txt","c.txt","d.txt"];

function forEachOf (array, asynchFunction, callbackWhenFinished) {
    let nbCalls = 0;
    array.forEach(item => asynchFunction(item, () => {
        // Wrapper function responsible of calling callback function
        // only once asynchronous job is done on all items of array
        if (++nbCalls === array.length)
            callbackWhenFinished();
    }));
}

var nbLinesTotal = 0;

forEachOf(
    files,
    (name, callback) => {
        // Write your asynchronous function here
        fs.readFile(name, 'utf-8', (error, data) => {
            if (!error)
                nbLinesTotal += data.toString().split("\n").length;
            // Wrapper function is called here: it seamlessly decides if it's time to call the real callback
            callback();
        });
    },
    () => {
        // Write your callback function here.
        // It will be called only once
        console.log(nbLinesTotal);
    }
);
```

---

**EDIT:** Doing some research I found there is a library that does exactly what I wrote: [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/v1.5.2/README.md). It's worth your giving it a try :-)